# Link to content in drupal 7 views tpl.php

Tags: drupal

i want to add link to its node in views-view-myview-unformatted.tpl.php via php. I am trying with $node_url but without succsess.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the rendering of a field of your view, you should do it at field level, and not at views level.

Take a look at this link : [theme!views-view-fields.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme!views-view-fields.tpl.php/7.x-3.x)